# websockets.exceptions.InvalidMessage: did not receive a valid HTTP response

Tags: python, docker

If you could spare some of your time please evaluate my error. Python websocketserver is perfectly running inside docker machine, but when I tried to run the client.py in my local machine only, it raised an error in the client end, even I am exposing the port in docker file EXPOSE 8080. Did I missed necessary process to access the websocketserver from docker ?

Error below:

````
websockets.exceptions.InvalidMessage: did not receive a valid HTTP response```
````

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe show code which you use. And configuration for docker. This way we could run it and test it.